# How to scroll after submit when page refresh and PHP set color of label to red to div with ID form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is when I click submit it refresh page when page is refreshed it stays on top without scrolling to div with id form?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('label').length > 0){
         $('label').each(function(){  
           if($(this).css('color') == 'red'){
            alert('test');
              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("form").offset().top
              }, 1000);
           }
         });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" name="ats_form">
  <div id="form" class=" ui-body ui-body-d"> <!-- element where I want to scroll -->
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
         <b>Kontaktní osoba</b>
      </legend>
       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <label for="f_FName">Jméno *</label> <!-- if this label is red, php script check input with regular expression when it is not filled or name is not enter properly then it set this label attribute css to color: red; -->
         <input id="f_FName" class="ui-input-text ui-body-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" type="text" value="" size="30" name="f_FName"> <!-- this is input that php check -->
       </div>
     </fieldset>    
   </div>
   <input class="btnform ui-btn-hidden" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Odeslat" aria-disabled="false">
</form>
```

HTML after php validation if input is for example empty or with wrong value:
    same structure as previous
      Jméno *
    same structure as previous

Comment: Guys I forgot to include my submit in form please check my edited post. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to set that timeout to more than 4sec but still without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('label[style*="color:red"]').length > 0) { //If there's a label with style*="color:red"...
    alert('scroll'); //...Alert
    $('html, body').animate({ //..animate to form
        scrollTop: $("form").offset().top
    }, 1000);
};
```

### [JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/q4v59/3/)

Put it in `$(document).ready`-event

Comment: In your style-attribute is no semicolon. I've edited the selector. Now it selects with or without ";" and gives an alarm.

Comment: Alex i still don't get it how you solve my problem you set check to css validation instead of jQuery ? Thank you for answer

Comment: I've edited your example-HTML-code for JSfiddle because there was no label with `color:red`. On submit your PHP will add color:red to your labels and after document.ready the jQuery-selector(`$('label[style*="color:red"]')`) selects all labels with `color:red` and begins to scroll to the form if there's one.